# Sails.js flash message for user registration

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I am following Sail.js tutorial from http://irlnathan.github.io/sailscasts/blog/2013/08/27/building-a-sails-application-ep4-handling-validation-errors-with-a-flash-message/

However I ran into a small problem. In the tutorial the author uses registration files inside his user folder and assigns routes in the user controller. He then sends validation errors using `flash` to the user.

However in my project, the registration files lies in the root folder and I assign the routes from the routes.js file like so

```
module.exports.routes = {

  '/': {
    view: 'index'
  },

  '/register': {
    view: 'register'
  }

};
```

Now the problem is to using flash to show users the validation errors while registration. I have used the following in the user controller (create) and it doesn't seem to work

```
if (err){
    err.success = 0;
    console.log(err);
    req.session.flash = {
        err: err   
    }
    req.flash('error', req.session.flash);
    return res.redirect('/register');
}
```

Any suggestions?

Sails.js version < 0.10.x based on his other thread output [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25367213/54964)

Comment: Please, state the complete solution to your problem here. I added the most likely sails.js version used here to make your case reproducible. It seems that your case was caused by the specific version characteristic as observed here https://stackoverflow.com/q/25356827/54964

Answer (score 16, accepted):

EDIT: See the Sails documentation [here](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Routes/RouteTargetSyntax.html?q=view-target-syntax) for more information - basically, since you're using static routing, no policies are applied before rendering the view, hence the flash policy isn't working. I'd recommend adding a `register` action in your `UserController` and just calling `res.view()` from there. There's also a [StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21303217/sailsjs-policy-based-route-with-a-view/21340313#21340313) that discusses this, if you want more information.

I do have an alternative I developed for my own project that you can try out (also requires non-static routing).

In your `api/policies` folder, create a policy `flash.js`:

```
// flash.js policy
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = { success: [], error: [], warning: [] };

  if(!req.session.messages) {
    req.session.messages = { success: [], error: [], warning: [] };
    return next();
  }
  res.locals.messages = _.clone(req.session.messages);

  // Clear flash
  req.session.messages = { success: [], error: [], warning: [] };
  return next();
};
```

This policy allows for three different flash types: success, warning, and error. It'll create an empty dictionary for each session and clear it on page loads.

I created a service `FlashService.js` in `api/services` to more easily flash messages:

```
// FlashService.js
module.exports = {
  success: function(req, message) {
    req.session.messages['success'].push(message);
  },
  warning: function(req, message) { 
    req.session.messages['warning'].push(message);
  },   
  error: function(req, message) {
    req.session.messages['error'].push(message);
  }
}
```

Then, in your `config/policies.js` config file, make sure to assign the `flash` policy to the controller actions that you want to use flash with:

```
// config/policies.js
module.exports.policies = {
  '*': [true, 'flash'],
  'UserController': {
    'register': ['flash'],
    // any future actions that want flash
  },
  'AnotherController': {
    'someAction': ['flash', 'somePolicy'],
  }
}
```

To flash a message in your `register` action, just use `FlashService.success(req, message)`. Alternatively, you can use `FlashService.error` and `FlashService.warning`, depending on how your UI styling works and how much you want to differentiate your flash messages.

In your view, you can put something like this:

```
<% if (messages && messages['error'].length > 0) { %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
  <% messages['error'].forEach(function(message) { %>
    <%= message %>
    <br>
  <% }); %>
  </div>
  <br>
<% } %>
<% if (messages && messages['warning'].length > 0) { %>
  <div class="alert alert-warning">
  <% messages['warning'].forEach(function(message) { %>
    <%= message %>
    <br>
  <% }); %>
  </div>
  <br>
<% } %>
<% if (messages && messages['success'].length > 0) { %>
  <div class="alert alert-success">
  <% messages['success'].forEach(function(message) { %>
    <%= message %>
    <br>
  <% }); %>
  </div>
  <br>
<% } %>
```

Of course, you'll have to change the `div` classes to whatever classes are relevant to your UI.

Comment: Your solution looks good and very organized. I did as you've suggested, however I don't receive any value for `messages` in the view. `messages` is always undefined :/

Comment: Ahh, because of the static routing, policies don't apply. What I would do is just map your ````register```` view to an action for the ````UserController````. That may also be why the flash policy isn't working in the tutorial you're following. See the Sails documentation [here](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Routes/RouteTargetSyntax.html?q=view-target-syntax) for more information. Edited my response above!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! :)
I added another question related to this if you could have a look at. Thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25356827/sails-js-non-static-routing-urls

Comment: I don't understand why you have to use `_.clone()` at all. Any tips?

Comment: See [this explanation on the difference between _.clone() and '='](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16961898/whats-the-difference-between-underscore-clone-and-simple). Essentially, you want to create a copy of the messages so that you can clear them for the user's next action. These flash messages aren't meant to be persistent across every page load.

Answer (score 3):

In a normal mvc like rails or cakephp handling flash is something like this: $this->Flash->error('An Error Occurred Message'); then displayed it in an element.

In sails it should be simple as that.

In Controller: req.flash('error', 'An Error Occurred Message');

In View Partial: flash.ejs

```html
<% if (req.session.flash) { %>

    <% if (req.session.flash.success) { %>
    <div data-alert class="alert-box success radius">
        <%= req.flash('success') %>
        <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
    </div>
    <% } %>

    <% if (req.session.flash.warning) { %>
    <div data-alert class="alert-box warning radius">
        <%= req.flash('warning') %>
        <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
    </div>
    <% } %>

    <% if (req.session.flash.error) { %>
    <div data-alert class="alert-box alert round">
        <%= req.flash('error') %>
        <a href="#" class="close">&times;</a>
    </div>
    <% } %>

<% } %>
```

On Layout:

```html
<%- partial('partials/flash') %>
```

Handling Error Message per field should be part in a Validation and Html Helper. (Like for example: https://gist.github.com/mikermcneil/8366092)

Answer (score 1):

You can add this export:

```
module.exports = function flash(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.session.flash) {
    req.session.flash = {};
    req.session.flash['success'] = [];
    req.session.flash['warning'] = [];
  }
  next();
};
```

and then in the view:

```
<% if (req.session.flash['success'].length > 0) { %>
<div class="alert alert-success">
  <%= req.session.flash['success'].pop() %>
</div>
<% } %>
<% if (req.session.flash['warning'].length > 0) { %>
<div class="alert alert-warning">
  <%= req.session.flash['warning'].pop() %>
</div>
<% } %>
```

You can create messages in the controller like this:

```
req.session.flash['success'].push('Updated successfully');
```