# Sails.js non-static routing urls

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

So I was working with this [Sails.js flash message for user registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25350841/sails-js-flash-message-for-user-registration) but then I got into a new issue. So basically I am using the following in the user controller to render non-static content of the `user/register.js` file to client.

```
'register': function(req, res){
    res.view();
},
```

This however means that the address to access the registration page will be `http://localhost/user/register`. Is it possible to change this url to work with `http://localhost/register` without webpage redirects (possibly from the above code itself)? This I believe can be handled using custom redirects [Custom Routes](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Routes/RouteTargetSyntax.html). But using redirects could be ugly at times?

Comment: A route is not a redirect.

Comment: @BenFortune But how do we establish `localhost/register` instead of `localhost/user/register` without redirection? I don't want `localhost/user/register` to exist at all. But so far I am stuck with it because I need to render dynamic content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You linked to right documentation, but didn't look in the right section.  You want to use the [controller/action custom route syntax](http://sailsjs.org/#/documentation/concepts/Routes/RouteTargetSyntax.html?q=controller-%2F-action-target-syntax) to route **/register** to the `UserController.register` action:

```
"/register": "UserController.register"
```

or

```
"/register": {controller: 'user', action: 'register'}
```

in your **config/routes.js** will do what you want.

To disable the default **/user/register** route, you can either 1) set `actions` to `false` in **config/blueprints.js** (this will turn off all default controller/action routing), or explicitly disable the route in **config/routes.js**:

```
"/user/register": {response: 'notFound'}
```

Comment: but won't this create two urls that can be accessed? `localhost/register` and `localhost/user/register`? I want to avoid this duplication and have the second link return a 404 error page?

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clear that you wanted this and *only* this route to work.  Updated my answer.

Comment: `"/user/register": {response: 'notFound'}` was not able to solve this, I am guessing because `'register': function(req, res){
    res.view();
},` is called later in the user controller? However, turning `actions` to `false` in `config/blueprints.js` did the trick. Thanks :)

Comment: Hm, the only reason `{response: 'notFound'}` shouldn't work is if you're not on Sails v0.10.x.  Custom routes takes precedence over everything else.

Comment: @pewpewlasers Please, provide a full answer which answer your own question. I started a wiki ticket so I can follow you below.

Answer (score 0):

OP's solution to the case in the comment.

> [I was not able to solve `"/user/register": {response: 'notFound'}` by sgress454 proposal]. However, turning `actions` to `false` in `config/blueprints.js` did the trick.

Sails version < 0.10.x because the other answer solution should work here.