# Flash message doesn't show until refresh or secondary post?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js

I am jumping into Sails.js again and working through to create flash messages throughout my app (for errors, successes, or alerts). I was looking for a good way to do it and [found this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25350841/sails-js-flash-message-for-user-registration), I implemented the solution they had suggested.

The general mechanism works great, however, the flash message is only seen after a secondary refresh or after another post. It does not show at first upon page load. Here is how I have everything structured and I am using `"sails": "~0.10.0-rc7"` currently:

In my `api/policies` folder, I have `flash.js`:

```
// flash.js policy
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = {
    success: [], 
    error: [], 
    warning: []
  };

  if(!req.session.messages) {
    req.session.messages = { success: [], error: [], warning: [] };
    return next();
  }

  res.locals.messages = _.clone(req.session.messages);

  // Clear flash
  req.session.messages = { success: [], error: [], warning: [] };
  return next();
};
```

In my `api/services`, I have `FlashService.js`:

```
// FlashService.js
module.exports = {

  success: function(req, message) {
    req.session.messages['success'].push(message);
  },

  warning: function(req, message) { 
    req.session.messages['warning'].push(message);
  },  

  error: function(req, message) {
    req.session.messages['error'].push(message);
  }
}
```

My `config/policies.js` is also configured with the `flash` policy:

```
// config/policies.js
module.exports.policies = {
  '*': [true, 'flash'],
  'UserController': {
    'join': ['flash'],
  },
};
```

Now, with all that setup, an example of how I am using it is in my `UserController` for my `join` action:

```
module.exports = {

    join: function(req, res) {

        // If username, email, and password compare come back true: create user.
        if(newUser.username && newUser.email && newUser.password == newUser.confirmPassword) {

            // Logic to create user.
            res.view();

        // If not, then report an issue.
        } else {

            FlashService.error(req, 'There was an issue.');
            res.view();

         };
    }
};
```

Finally, my view is exactly the same code as that discussion I linked. I am using `EJS` on this:

```
<% if (messages && messages['error'].length > 0) { %>
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
  <% messages['error'].forEach(function(message) { %>
    <%= message %>
    <br>
  <% }); %>
  </div>
  <br>
<% } %>
<% if (messages && messages['warning'].length > 0) { %>
  <div class="alert alert-warning">
  <% messages['warning'].forEach(function(message) { %>
    <%= message %>
    <br>
  <% }); %>
  </div>
  <br>
<% } %>
<% if (messages && messages['success'].length > 0) { %>
  <div class="alert alert-success">
  <% messages['success'].forEach(function(message) { %>
    <%= message %>
    <br>
  <% }); %>
  </div>
  <br>
<% } %>
```

What could I be doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your messages are being read before the the controller is executed (and just message is set after it is read). The req object is available in your view, you should just read req.session.messages['xxxx']  directly into your view.